# Opening an Excel document from SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to open an Excel workbook from SharePoint using PowerShell. I'm not loading the SharePoint snap-in—I do not have it.

When PowerShell tries to launch the workbook, SharePoint prompts for credentials. The problem is that we're trying to schedule the script, and we would like the script to have an SSO-like experience.

Here's the MWE:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open(http://site/file.xlsx)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($WorksheetName)
$Excel.Visible = $false

# some Excel manipulation

$Workbook.Close($false)
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable Excel
```

Comment: For actions like these you should use the REST API. Documentation can be found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx and it should support downloading files (since we use SP 2016 and SP Online my code examples for this are useless for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, download the SharePoint file locally, then open, manipulate, etc.

The example below uses the default creds of the user running the script/PowerShell session.

```
$fromfile = "http://site/file.xlsx"
$tofile   = "c:\somedirectory\file.xlsx"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$webclient.DownloadFile($fromfile, $tofile)

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($tofile)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($WorksheetName)
$Excel.Visible = $false

# some Excel manipulation

$Workbook.Close($false)
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable Excel
```

Answer (score 6):

I have recently run into the same issue.
I solved it without saving it to the local machine.

The COM Excel object's WorkBook property has a method so called CheckIn and CheckOut. You will need to use both.

Also, to directly open a file from Sharepoint, just go for the library on the Sharepoint page, open it in explorer. 
You will get something like this:

> http://sitename/sites/TeamSite/FileLibrary/

You only need to replace the path for an UNC path like this:

> \\sitename\sites\TeamSite\FileLibrary\

(With Double backslash at the begininning)

```
$ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open("\\sitename\sites\TeamSite\FileLibrary\test.xlsx")
$ExcelObject.Workbooks.CheckOut("\\sitename\sites\TeamSite\FileLibrary\test.xlsx")

$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item(1)

#This part selects the A:1 cell and changes it's value.
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Edited text"

$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.CheckIn()
```

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately, we’ve moved away from the system that required this. I’ll try this out when I get a chance.