# PowerShell WebClient downloads leaves corrupted file

Tags: excel, powershell

I am running the following PowerShell to try and download an Excel xlsx formatted spreadsheet form SharePoint.

```
$ExcelFileLocal = 'C:\Temp\Test.xlsx'
$ExcelFileRemote = '<long https url to Excel file taken from SharePoint using Copy Shortcut command>'
$credentials = Get-Credential -UserName $strName
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = $credentials 
$webclient.DownloadFile($ExcelFileRemote, $ExcelFileLocal)
```

When trying to open the file with Excel or a new COM object in PowerShell the following error is given:

> Excel cannot open the file 'Test.xlsx' because the file format or file
>   extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted
>   and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

If a test using a .txt file instead of an Excel file there is no problem in opening the resultant file.

The answer listed here: [Opening an Excel document from SharePoint using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676858/opening-an-excel-document-from-sharepoint-using-powershell) gives the same error as shown.

EDIT:

The file I am trying to download and further work on appears to  be XML and can be opened in a text editor to show this header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><title>
```

A more simple .xlsx file I have tested with successfully doesn't have this XML format and can be further processed. Not sure why this difference is coming about.

Comment: Have you tried to open the downloaded file in notepad or whatever to see what was its content? Is the file size what you would expect?

Comment: @DavidBrabant - The file size is larger than expected around 80Kb (expected around 20KB). The method works Ok with a different test xlsx file so it seems there is something wrong with the xlsx file I am targetting. The targetted file can be opened find via SharePoint >> Edit in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long URL was wrong - Correct now works as expected.