# Powershell - Suppress Excel Dialog Box - Merge Changes with Server

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have Powershell script that calls an Excel VBA script and saves the file. I'm running into an issue while closing the workbook as I get a dialog box `"Would you like to merge your changes with the latest updates on the Server?"` and PowerShell waits for user confirmation. How do I suppress this notification? I have enabled displayAlerts = $false but that doesn't seems to be working in this case

The file sits on a shared onedrive folder location which is prompting Excel to ask this question

```
 $file="test - Copy v4.xlsm"
 $x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
 $x1.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
 $x1.Visible = $false
 $wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
 $x1.Run('MACRO_NAME')
 $wb.Save()
 $wb.Close()
 $x1.Quit()
 Remove-Variable wb,x1
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `SaveAs()` to the same path? As an aside, I prefer using this module to the ComObject - [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: It errors out at   Cannot access 'vb test - Copy v5.xlsm'.
  At line:26 char:5
  +     $wb.SaveAs("C:\vb t ...
  +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Can I run macros using the ImportExcel module?

Comment: Try this - `SaveAs($filename, 52, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $false, $false, 1, 2)` - [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas). Parameters explained named in order `FileName, FileFormat (52 for xlsm), Password (Can't be null, so use Type.Missing), WriteResPassword (Type missing again), ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, Access Mode (1 - do not change access mode), ConflictResolution (2 - User changes always accepted)`. You can see links to some of the values on the linked page.

Comment: If I use `SaveAs($filename)` the document gets saved to the My Documents Folder instead of the folder path that it is originally in. I tried passing the full path of the file and I get this error `Unable to get the SaveAs property of the Workbook class
At line:1 char:1
+ $wb.SaveAs("C:\Users\*\OneDrive \*\vb test  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

Answer (score 0):

I might have stumbled upon a solution. Instead of using Save or SaveAS and trying to pass parameters, I used the Workbook.Close Method and passed True as a parameter which solved my problem

Please note that if others are making changes on Excel online, this might result in merge issues. There's a checkin() and checkout() method that I'm trying to implement which should take care of this problem as well:
[Opening an Excel document from SharePoint using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676858/opening-an-excel-document-from-sharepoint-using-powershell)

```
 $file="test - Copy v4.xlsm"
 $x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
 $x1.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
 $x1.Visible = $false
 $wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
 $x1.Run('MACRO_NAME')
 $wb.Save()
 $wb.Close($true)
 $x1.Quit()
 Remove-Variable wb,x1
```